# How can I mount a local drive in remote machine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, mount

I would like to mount a local (one I have physical access to) drive on a google compute engine vm.

Any links on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/). It's written for Ubuntu, since you have not specified what OS you are running locally. You will need to make sure that your machine is running SSH server.

Another thing to keep in mind is local port forwarding. If you are behind a NAT you must specify the IP of your system in the firewall or router in order to accept incoming connections on port 22 (or whatever port you decide on).

If you provide info on your OS type, I can help you further.

Comment: I am running locally on Fedora and CentOS remotely (on google cloud). Let me try the tutorial you point to.